# How to differentiate different types of Web Services according to URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

So I have finally created a VERY simple application in which I invoke a web service and NSLog the JSON data. I have used about 3 web services so far, and all of them look different. For example, in the small little app I made I used two different URLS. My code is below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ielmo.xtreemhost.com/array.php"];

    NSString *urlString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bookapi.bignerdranch.com/courses.json"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString2];

    NSData *data = [NSData  dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", json);
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

My question is how come I can NSLog BOTH of those link's json data fine even if one of them is a .php url. Sorry for such a nooby question but I want to go about looking for web services I can use, and I want to be able to know how to look, because when I look for my own web services, they don't end up  working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way you can differentiate the content of a URL by the URL itself (unless it's an HTML)

The contents of a URL depend on what the server wants to serve. You can have an `http://www..../something.php` for example, and there's no way to know what you'll get, it could be an HTML page, it could be a PDF document, it could be a zip file, or it could be JSON content.

Comment: Thanks, also is the code I have above what you could say "the latest and greatest way" of calling a web service? I'm trying to be AS SIMPLISTIC as possible and attempting to get this to work at the same time. But I also don't want to have something working under poor code.